# Spring JdbcTemplate and oracle arrayofnumber

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-jdbc

I'm using Spring and Oracle database in my solution and i need to execute script

```
select count(1) from ELEMENTS, table(cast(? as arrayofnumbers)) session_ids
                                        where root_session_id in session_ids.VALUE
```

but i have a problem with passing input parameter.

i try to pass List or array of BigInteger into

```
JdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(1) from ELEMENTS, table(cast(? as arrayofnumbers)) session_ids
                                            where root_session_id in session_ids.VALUE", Integer.class, INPUT_PARAMS)
```

but has an Exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8861)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8338)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9116)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObject(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9093)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObject(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:234)
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.setObject(PreparedStatement.java:357)
```

Does anyone have the same problem?

EDIT:

Forget to describe arrayofnumber. It's custom type:

```
TYPE arrayofnumbers as table of number(20)
```

Comment: I don't know if you can do that with the stanadart jdbc. I think you can use the classes from the oracle jdbc driver, it hast arrays and other classes that correspond to the oracle types.

Comment: Also arrayofnumbers doesen't sound like a valid type to cast to...

Comment: please, find a description of arrayofnumber type in the main comment

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution:

```
final BigInteger[] ids = new BigInteger[]{BigInteger.valueOf(9137797712513092132L)};


    int count = jdbc.query("select count(1) from NC_DATAFLOW_ELEMENTS\n" +
            "  where root_session_id in (select /*+ cardinality(t 10) */ * from table(cast (? as arrayofnumbers)) t)"
            , new PreparedStatementSetter() {
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement) throws SQLException {
            Connection conn = preparedStatement.getConnection();
            OracleConnection oraConn = conn.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
            oracle.sql.ARRAY widgets = oraConn.createARRAY("ARRAYOFNUMBERS", ids);
            preparedStatement.setArray(1, widgets);
        }
    }, new ResultSetExtractor<Integer>() {
                public Integer extractData(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                    resultSet.next();
                    return resultSet.getInt(1);
                }
            });

    out.println(count);
```

should note that type of array (ARRAYOFNUMBER) should be in upper case